# how to render dataSet in datatable using javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets, datatables

I'm trying to concatenate the string to pass it to the datatable, I got the data from servlets, when I put static string it works but I don't know how to handle it using loop as it's dynamic data

```
function getMsgHandler(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
    alert(responseTxt);
    if (statusTxt === "success") {
        products = responseTxt;
        var s = "";
        for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                s = s + '[' + products[i].productID + ', "' + products[i].name + '", "' + products[i].description + '", "' + products[i].img + '", ' + products[i].price + ' ]';
            } else {
                s = s + ', [' + products[i].productID + ', "' + products[i].name + '", "' + products[i].description + '", "' + products[i].img + '", ' + products[i].price + ']';
            }
        }
        dataSet = '[ ' + s + ' ]';
        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: dataSet
        });
    }
}
```

I want it to be like this format

```
var dataSet = [
    ["m", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"]
];
```

Comment: I think it would be quite a bit easier if you show us the data you have, and what you want. If you control the server, it would probably be easier to just output the correct format directly.

Comment: the format you want is an array of arrays.  you should approach it from that standpoint, and not a string with brackets concatenated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below instead:

```
function getMsgHandler(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
    if (statusTxt === "success") {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            data: responseTxt,
            columns: [
               { data: 'productID' },
               { data: 'name' },
               { data: 'description' },
               { data: 'img' },
               { data: 'price' }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @AyaRadwan, please post the content of `responseTxt`.